# Magento - Show all items including tax on Paypal order summary

Tags: magento, paypal

When checking out with Paypal standard on Magento, the order summary shows all prices not including tax, then the tax is added on at the end. See the picture below:

[image]

I need it so that rather than adding the tax separately at the end, the summary is kept nice and simple like this:

**Item 1:** £25.00

**Shipping:** £2.75

**Total:** £27.95

I have set all my Magento settings to include tax in all prices (see below):

[image]

I'm not sure what else I can do to get it to transfer the prices across including tax only. Does anybody have any experience with this? I'm hoping there's no need for a core hack.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that you can't change this, as it's on Paypal's end.

Comment: Any idea how you change it on Paypal's end? Or do we need to look at hacking the core Paypal modules so it passes tax as zero?